# .htaccess how to route / and /subdirectory to root directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website where I need `www.website.com/` and `www.website.com/men` to both point to the root directory. I don't want to redirect I just want to point to same directory and then I'll pick out the URL and modify the content. Here is my current .htaccess mod_rewrite block:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks 
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteRule ^(components|images|scripts|styles|views)($|/) - [L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

My site is a SPA where everything is routed via index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteRule ^men/?$ / [L,NC]
```